# Very long words not wrapping in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

I have an issue where if a user was to enter a long comment/word such as 'cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool' this would break the formatting on the page.

Here is an image below to help explain the scenario (not to scale) and also the code used:

[image]

**Html:**

```
<div class="comment-content">
    <p>cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool</p>
    <br />
    <a class="delete-comment" data-delete-comment-id="28" href="/">Delete</a>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.comment-content
{
    width: 525px; 
    margin: 13px 25px 0 0;
}
.comment-content p
{
    width: 525px;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a quick fix for this without changing too much markup and CSS as this is area of code we would not want to introduce bugs by changing the application code (written in ASP.NET/MVC 3).

If CSS/Html was not an option I guess the HTML 5 `<wbr>` Tag could be used to seperate the word after 'x' amount of characters - the only issue with this is that the website is multi lingual in 9 languages. Japanese and Chinese for instance the text characters are significantly larger then English text characters which would need multiple conditional code for these to get the character count before adding the `<wbr>` or the font size decreased. Just after suggestions on the best solution really.

Many Thanks

Comment: try giving maxlength in input tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this**

```
.comment-content p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/1ptzeG0G)***

***[More Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap)***

Comment: Breaking strings at arbitrary points is hardly a perfect solution. It distorts the content, turning “foobar” to “foob ar” or “fooba r”. For any real solution, the principles of processing the text content must be defined.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like it to be nicely capped as: oooooo...
use:

```
.comment-content .p{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If there are more than one line, use

```
.comment-content .p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I actually have use for your first answer as well as the answer which Rohit posted which worked for me. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```css
.class {
    resize:none;
}
```